# Get transaction in mainnet from layer2 rollup

Tags: etherscan, layer-2, rollups

With the coming of optimistic & ZKP rollups, I was wondering how we will be able to retrieve transaction data through etherscan.io generated from a layer2 solution.

Let's put an example:

- Platform **A** operates with optimistic rollups, so creates a batch of 2000 transactions in a side-chain, and puts just one transaction **T** in the mainnet that relates to these 2000 tx's.

If one transaction **T'** out of these 2000 tx's was a transfer of ETH between two accounts generated from platform A:

1. How do I check transaction **T'** in the mainnet if I don't have a reference to its origin in a side-chain, but just one transaction **T**?
2. Are there certain transactions in a side-chain that can't be batched? for instance, if it is a withdrawal, should this create one specific transaction in the mainnet instead of including it in a batch **T**?
3. If there are different rollup platforms, will we have to go to the block explorer -if available- of each individual platform to see the details from the batched transactions?